# merging files with dependencies - require js

Tags: requirejs

I'm using require JS.
I want to marge two files into one.
I'm using for that require js plugin for grunt.
First file is [raty jquery script](http://wbotelhos.com/raty).

Second is my own file like this:

```
define('userGlosowanie', ['jquery', 'raty'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        init: function () {
        }
    }
});
```

And here is my grunt script:

```
requirejs: {
    userGlosowanie: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "js/libs",
            paths: {
                userGlosowanie: "../dev/uzytkownik-glosowanie",
                raty: "raty/jquery.raty",
            },
            name: "userGlosowanie",
            out: "js/build/uzytkownik.min.js",
            preserveLicenseComments: false,

        }
    },
},
```

Problem is that I've got error:

```
Running "requirejs:user" (requirejs) task
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> 'D:\strony\www\polskieszlaki\js\libs\jquery.js'
>> In module tree:
>>     user
Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue.
```

my jquery file is in separate file and I don't want to include it in compiled file. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include `jquery` in build file just mark it as `empty:` in path config.

```
options: {
    paths: {
        userGlosowanie: "../dev/uzytkownik-glosowanie",
        raty: "raty/jquery.raty",
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude a particular module/file from getting included in the combined/optimized file using the `exclude` option

In your case it will look like -

```
    requirejs: {
        userGlosowanie: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: "js/libs",
                paths: {
                    userGlosowanie: "../dev/uzytkownik-glosowanie",
                    raty: "raty/jquery.raty",
                },
                out: "js/build/uzytkownik.min.js",
                name: "userGlosowanie",
                exclude: "jquery" 
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
        }
     }
}
```

With `modules` and `dir`(output dir) option, you may not be able to set the output file name, but the optmized file with same name as the module will be placed in the directory set by option `dir`

```
    requirejs: {
        userGlosowanie: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: "js/libs",
                paths: {
                    userGlosowanie: "../dev/uzytkownik-glosowanie",
                    raty: "raty/jquery.raty",
                },
                dir: "../public",
                modules : [{
                name: "userGlosowanie",
                exclude: "jquery"
                }],
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
           }
     }
}
```

Sample usage/explanation is [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)

Comment: It's not working : { [Error: Error: If the "modules" option is used, then there should be a "dir" option set and "out" should not be used since "out" is only for single file optimization output.
    at Function.build.createConfig (D:\strony\www\polskieszlaki\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:26899:19)
]
  originalError: [Error: If the "modules" option is used, then there should be a "dir" option set and "out" should not be used since "out" is only for single file optimization output.] }

Comment: Updated my answer - please try with the exclude option at the root level..if that does not work, alternative is to - as error message suggested is to use a 'dir' and modules option

Comment: exclude in root is not working either - tried that. Don't want to use dir because it's coping all files - don't need it.

Comment: Never used this option, but skipDirOptimize: true option is what you may need if you want to prevent copying/optimizing all files. Documentation is bit hazy